# Setting up a honey-pot on own PC

Tags: honeypot

Even though honey pots are set up on isolated machines, is there a way to configure a honey pot on a normal PC with Windows 7 installed? I am studying the heuristic capabilities of various anti-malware engines to learn how effective they are in a variety of situations.

Comment: I would suggest dual booting to be extra safe, but you can always just use a vm... virtualbox and vmware player are free.

Comment: Maybe better suited to security.SE?

Comment: Oh yes. There is a new Security forum on StackExchange network.

Comment: Use a VM on a different network.

Comment: Just a friendly warning, if you do choose to go down the VM route, you still [need to protect yourself adequately](http://superuser.com/questions/289054/is-my-host-machine-completely-isolated-from-a-virus-infected-virtual-machine).  And I don't just mean anti-virus software.

Comment: @KCotreau, I don’t think that would be practical; it sounds like Rohit is simply trying to learn and does not have access to a big budget for dedicated hardware/networks/etc. just for this purpose. I myself use my main “production” system as my testing box since I don’t have extra systems. (Yes, it creates problems sometimes, but those are good learning experiences in and of themselves.)