# Run a Virtual Machine inside a Rackspace Cloud Server?

Tags: virtualization, cloud

Is it possible to run some semblance of a Virtual Machine (perhaps not something as comprehensive as VMWare / VirtualBox, but something like User-Space Linux) inside of a Rackspace Cloud Virtual Server?

I have a bunch of Rackspace Cloud Servers created to experiment with various things and I'm just wondering if I can save some money by consolidating them all into a single bigger virtual server.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I cannot see why this would not work, even with VMWare and the like. Just because it is in the cloud, it is still a real server, and people here have asked about running VM's within VM's with positive answers.

The only thing I would say is make sure you have enough RAM for each simultaneous VM you plan to run, and you will probably have to use NAT'ed network cards unless you are able to buy multiple IP addresses.

[Can you run a machine emulator (Bochs) inside a virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/312433/can-you-run-one-virtual-machine-inside-another)

Answer (score 0):

As long as your linux kernel supports it, you could run OpenVZ containers.  They are lightweight OS virtualized containers.  You can give them their own IP addresses and limit their memory and cpu.