# Linux VirtualBox inside Windows VirtualBox doesn't boot

Tags: linux, windows, boot, virtualbox, linux-mint

I'm trying to run a Linux VirtualBox instance inside a Windows 7 VirtualBox instance, but Linux (tried both Puppy and Mint) doesn't boot.

My research says that this should be possible, see here for example: [Can you run a machine emulator (Bochs) inside a virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/312433/can-you-run-one-virtual-machine-inside-another) but I can't get it to work.

Here are a couple of screenshots showing where the boot process stops for Linux Mint and Puppy Linux.

[image: Linux Mint stuck during boot]
[image: Puppy Linux stuck during boot]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** So, it should indeed be possible according to the [VirtualBox forums](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=20589%20VirtualBox%20forums). But it is not supported. And if you do get it running it will probably be slow.

Doing this is called "Nested virtualization". Googling for that gives many hits. For example a link to the [VMWare Workstation 9.0 changelog](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws90/doc/workstation-90-release-notes.html#Nested) that mentions support for nested virtualization

Comment: are you using Bochs?

Comment: No. Just VirtualBox. Not even sure what Bochs is truth to be told.

Comment: @Tobbe - http://bochs.sourceforge.net/ should help you answer matpol's question

Comment: Yeah, I've read it. Did so before my answer :) Still wasn't 100% sure what it was. Some kind of computer emulator. Old and slower than virtualization

Comment: Is this some kind of class project? Who would want to run a VM inside a VM, if she can run two VMs in parallel? Stated otherwise: what is the use?

Comment: Hehe, no, not a class project. I'm not in school any longer :) I'm trying to do some weird networking experiments

Comment: in the question you reference they talk about bochs not a vb in vb but vb in bochs

Comment: Yes, I noticed that after you asked about Bochs :)