# Running virtual machines on a virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

I would like to have several virtual machines, to start and stop them at will. But the base machine is itself virtual. Is this doable? Which virtualisation software is capable of doing this?

Comment: No; it's not doable

Comment: Duplicate of [Can You Run One Virtual Machine Inside Another](http://superuser.com/questions/312433/can-you-run-one-virtual-machine-inside-another)