# How to run OS X inside VirtualBox inside OS X inside VirtualBox

Tags: macos, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I want to have the following virtualization configuration:

```
Real Apple Hardware: MacBook Pro 13" (2014)
  VirtualBox
    OS X 10.10
       VirtualBox
          OS X 10.10
```

Why? A real reason, actually. I want a CI environment that can be run on each individual developer's machine. So that's the first VirtualBox. Within there, I have several iOS apps that I want to compile independently and which talk with each other over TCP/IP.

Normally you can only run one iOS Simulator at a time. There's workarounds, but I'd rather avoid the workarounds and build and compile and run each iOS app in it's own fully isolated OS X virtual machine.

So I'd have one nested OS X 10.10 VM for App A, another for App B, and then as part of CI, App A and App B would talk to each other over TCP/IP.

Found this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/760318/155495) which seems to indicate it might not be possible. (Since OS X 10.10 is 64 bit.)

However, I'd love it if someone could prove me wrong.

I don't want to run multiple virtual machines at the root level because I want to be able to take a snapshot of the entire system of running virtual machines.

Note: The linked question is asking about running Bochs nested, which is not the same as running OS X nested.

Comment: Why don't you just have your host, start up a second VM, rather than nesting?  You'll get a lot better performance that way.