# Is it secure to execute a virus infected file using SandBox?

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is my host machine completely isolated from a virus-infected virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/289054/is-my-host-machine-completely-isolated-from-a-virus-infected-virtual-machine)

Is it secure to execute an infected file using Sandbox ?

Comment: Possible duplication with http://superuser.com/questions/289054/is-my-host-machine-completely-isolated-from-a-virus-infected-virtual-machine

Comment: I was asking for user reviews.