# Are there any pros/cons to enabling virtualization on my computer?

Tags: virtualization, hardware-virtualization

If I am not using any virtualization software on my computer, do I gain or lose anything by enabling (or disabling) x86 virtualization?

Comment: related: https://serverfault.com/questions/390012/why-do-systems-generally-disable-virtualization-by-default-in-bios-settings

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.  Intel VT technology is only useful when running programs that are **compatible** with it, and **actually use it**.  AFAIK, the only useful tools that can do this are sandboxes and virtual machines.  Even then, enabling this technology *can* be a [security risk](https://superuser.com/a/308246/6887) in some cases.  Often, virtualization technology is not required to emulate x86 or x86-64 instructions, albeit at the expense of speed.

As a best practice, I would leave it explicitly disabled unless required.

Answer (score 4):

while it is true you should not enable VT unless you really use it, there is no more risk if the feature is on or not. you need to protect your system the best you can, whether it is for virtualization or not.

VT makes nothing possible that was not possible before!

http://x86vmm.blogspot.com/2006/08/blue-pill-is-quasi-illiterate.html

Comment: Actually, VT *does* make something possible that wasn't before - it allows for a program running under an operating system to obtain full control of the CPU (which is impossible under any modern operating system *without* virtualization).  Although I do agree that you can do just as much without virtualization as you can with (gotta love Turing completeness :).

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any reference for that "full control"? Not really want to make it a polemic, because my understanding is that it makes the virtual cpu appear to have the full control of cpu, but actually not, but adding additional instructions? Intel source itself also seems to disagree: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/virtualization/virtualization-technology/hardware-assist-virtualization-technology.html and from what heard, the recent versions makes VT-enabled chips more secure with Intel TXT.

Comment: I read that in the [Intel 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html).  It literally allows a VM to execute x86 code directly on the CPU, avoiding a performance penalty incurred if you were to simply emulate the CPU (which is required without virtualization support).